# Paypal express payment method in magento 2.1 and it is not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment

> security header is not valid (# 10002)

Both PayPal and Magento forums indicate that the error is due to errors password and / or key.

Indeed the error exists, but is not in writing. Magento 2 not properly stored credentials, as indicated in the post [here][1].

Whether credentials are erased as if they are changed, the same number of characters always appears.

I tried to erase the credentials, empty the cache and then return them to enter... but nothing.

I searched the table in which to store this data, but the tables related to PayPal:

```
paypal_billing_agreement, paypal_billing_agreement_order, paypal_cert, paypal_payment_transaction, paypal_settlement_report, paypal_settlement_report_row
```

None of these tables stores data related credentials Signature API, the table "cert" would store certificates exclusively.

Where credentials are stored PayPal? Is this a bug in Magento?

Also **Paypal is not showing in frontend**. I dont know what is the problem.